# npm installing itself without dependancies

Tags: node.js, npm, centos6

I am trying to install the latest npm, following the instructions on [the npm doc site](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node).

My problem is that using command:

```
npm install -g npm
```

to get the latest version of NPM does not seem to work: it does not seem to install any of the needed dependencies, so when I run it I get errors such as:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/harmic/.node_modules/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

I am using a Centos 6 machine, so I started by installing node + npm from EPEL, like this:

```
yum install nodejs npm
```

That went OK. I then went to install the latest npm, as recommended at the above link and many other pages I've seen. My first attempt

```
sudo npm install -g npm
```

was not so great, for two reasons:

1. It installed in `/usr/lib/node_modules`, over the top of the original RPM installation. I judged this to be extremely poor practice, because the next time I did `yum update` on the system there was every chance the newly installed files would be overwritten by whatever incoming RPM packages contained, leaving an unholy mess.
2. It did not work anyway: I could not start npm at all, it constantly complained of missing dependancies as described above.

So I uninstalled the RPMs, removed all the left over files, then reinstalled the RPMs again. This time I created a `~/.npmrc` file and put this in it:

```
prefix = ${HOME}/.node_modules
```

I also set NODE_PATH environment variable to include that path. After this, npm did install itself in my desired location, but did not install any dependencies:

```
$ npm install -g npm
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
/home/harmic/.node_modules/bin/npm -> /home/harmic/.node_modules/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
npm@3.3.3 /home/harmic/.node_modules/lib/node_modules/npm
```

Running it from the new installed path gave the error at the top of the page.

Despite thinking that I must be doing something seriously wrong, I set about trying to install the unmet dependencies, one at a time:

```
npm install -g are-we-there-yet
npm install -g gauge
npm install -g os-tmpdir
npm install -g os-homedir
npm install -g is-absolute
npm install -g asap
npm install -g path-is-absolute
npm install -g builtins
npm install -g validate-npm-package-license
npm install -g concat-stream
npm install -g json-parse-helpfulerror
npm install -g readdir-scoped-modules
npm install -g debuglog
npm install -g lodash._baseclone
npm install -g lodash._bindcallback
npm install -g lodash._baseflatten
npm install -g lodash._baseuniq
...
```

and still it complains about needing more.

Finally I have concluded that I must have missed something important, so I decided to ask for the help of the SO community...

The initially installed versions of node & npm RPMs are:

- nodejs-0.10.36-3.el6
- npm-1.3.6-5.el6

Oh and in case you are wondering, the reason I am trying to update npm in the first place is because when trying to install [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/java) I ran into a build error, the solution to which is apparently to install an updated npm.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I would suggest you to forget to install node with RPM/APT etc, the reason for this is because normally they have outdate versions. Infact 0.10 is very old, 0.12 is nearly a year old and now there's 4.1 already. So my suggestion is to use `nvm` https://github.com/creationix/nvm

`nvm` is a Node Version Manager. the cool think is that you can switch version with a single command and stay always updated. After installing the node version that you want, you can also upgrade npm.

You can even select a node version for a certain folder in your system (if you have code that runs just in an old version for example)

Comment: Avoiding RPMs may be ok for my development environment, but it won't be feasible when it comes to deployment. I cannot expect sysadmins to learn and manage multiple package management systems, version managers, etc. But I will check out nvm for my dev environment at least.

Comment: But at this point, in the servers will be their problem to upgrade the version that is not provided by RPM, they can compile ;)

Comment: Using `nvm` is rather easier than trying apt/rpm to get things right.